# JavaScript Cookie Generator

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, web

Here's my target:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
function changerScript()
{
var x = document.getElementById('changethis');
var y = document.getElementById('textinputter').value;
var z = '");';

if(y == "")
{
alert('Please enter your JavaScript code, then click the Submit button.');
}
else
{
x.innerHTML = ('javascript:void(document.cookie="' + y + z);
alert('JavaScript String Successfully Generated!');
}
}
</script>

<div align="center">
<input type="text" id="textinputter" />
<button type="button" onClick="changerScript()">Submit</button>
</div>

<br /><hr />

<div align="center">
<p id="changethis"></p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Now when you're dealing with Cookies, I know there work like this:

```
javascript:void(document.cookie="Cookie=cookiedata;");
```

How do I add multiple cookie's like in the example above because

```
javascript:void(document.cookie="Cookie=cookiedata; Cookie2=cookiedata2;");
```

doesn't work?

Initially, I'd like to paste in the Cookie data (`Cookie1=cookie1data; Cookie2=cookie2data; Cookie3=cookie3data;`) and have JavaScript generate the code for me so then I can paste the code into Chrome's URL Bar and set the cookies with the generated JavaScript string.

Answer (score 0):

`document.cookie` just accepts one value at a time. Besides that document.cookie accepts three parameters: cookie name, value, and expire date.

You can grab the URL paramaters from `location.search` and then you can reuse the following method to set a cookie. Just use a for loop structure to get through all the params and set the cookie for each one.

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

For more info, please refer to [JavaScript Cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how would I implement this into what I want to do with my script above?